# How to change menu order item

Tags: php, functions, menus

Hello I have a main menu in my website

```
Home | How to start | about | contact | categories
```

but I add one item that lists all categories in functions.php

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'category_list', 10, 2);
function category_list($items, $args)
{
    if( $args->theme_location == 'header' )
    {
        $items .= '<li id="menu-item-184" class="parent menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-184"><a href=""#"">Kategorie</a><ul class="sub-menu">';
        $categories = get_categories();
        foreach ($categories as $category)
        {
            $option = '<li><a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'">';
            $option .= $category->cat_name;
            $option .= '</a></li>';
            $items .= $option;
        }

        $items .= '</ul></li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
How
```

How I can change the order of this item. I can't see it in Appearance->menu I want to move it to second position in menu.

```
Home | Categories | How to start | about | contact
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't order it through the wordpress Menu if you're using a filter. The worpdress menu system gives you the option to add Categories just as you add pages. If you don't see it, go to Appearance -> Menu and then go to Screen Options (top right of the page) and make sure the option Categories is checked.

Comment: Yes, I know it but I need to add categories to my menu automatically. When I create new category it should appear in menu too.

Comment: Maybe you should add that to the question? Pretty import info.

Comment: I did it but answer wont works.